# Stripe wants client_id parameter when 3D Secure is on - Stack: ReactNative, Tipsi, iOS

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments, react-native-ios

After several hours of development and digging through the outdated [Tipsi documentation](https://tipsi.github.io/tipsi-stripe/docs/example.html), as well as digging through the [Stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs), I was not able to find a solution to my problem.

My stack looks like:

- Client: ReactNative and [Stripe via Tipsi package](https://tipsi.github.io/tipsi-stripe/docs/index.html)
- Server: Node.js

I just want to enable my app customers to pay via credit card. I do the following approach, which is recommended by Stripe.

```
1. Client/App --> [REQUEST PAYMENT METHOD ID] --> Stripe Server
2. Stripe Server --> [RETURNS PAYMENT METHOD ID] --> Client/App
3. Client/App --> [SEND PAYMENT METHOD ID] --> Server (NodeJS)
4. Server --> [CREATE PAYMENT INTENT w/ STRIPE SECRET KEY] --> Stripe Server
5. Stripe Server --> [SENDS BACK 'OK' OR 'ACTION_REQUIRED'] --> Server
6. Server --> [IF 'ACTION_REQUIRED'] --> Client/App
7. Client/App --> [USER AUTHENTICATION] --> Stripe
8. Stripe --> [PAYMENT DONE] --> Server
```

Everything works great when no `action_required` is returned. So when a customer enters the credit card details, and no authentication or 3D Secure is requested from his/her bank, then the payment goes through. However, when I test my application with the test credit card from Stripe (Credit Card Number: `4000 0027 6000 3184`), which always asks for 3D Secure, my application stops at `Step 6`.

```
Error: Only Stripe Connect platforms can work with other accounts. If you specified a 
client_id parameter, make sure it's correct. If you need to setup a Stripe Connect platform,
you can do so at https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/applications/settings.
```

I do the following call at Step 7:

```
import Stripe from 'tipsi-stripe';
Stripe.setOptions({
  publishableKey: 'pk_test_51IA2...Ji7tr',
  merchantId: '<MERCHANT_ID>',
  androidPayMode: 'test',
});

Stripe.setStripeAccount(null)    

const handleAuthenticationChallenge = async () => {
  let response = null
  try {
    const authResponse = await Stripe.authenticatePaymentIntent({
      clientSecret: stripeClientSecret
    })
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
  return response
}
```

It seems that I use the function `Stripe.authenticatePaymentIntent` incorrectly, but I was not able to find anything regarding this, wether with [Tipsi](https://tipsi.github.io/tipsi-stripe/docs/index.html), nor with [Stripe](http://stripe.com).

Do I need to apply for [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/connect) in order to get a `client_id`? I just want to do a basic payment transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error occurs when you attempt to retrieve an account (e.g. GET `/v1/accounts/acct_123`) that isn't your own without being a Connect platform.

The problem is likely due to the line

```
Stripe.setStripeAccount(null)
```

You'd use this to specify that you're performing the Stripe API requests on behalf of a [connected account](https://github.com/tipsi/tipsi-stripe/blob/c74f6dc064415219fe87d843f5b6cf1044a67adf/website/docs-md/usage.md#L29). Setting it to `null` without having set it to a valid account ID initially is possibly doing something weird in tipsi-stripe. I'd try removing the line altogether if you intend for the request to be made on on your own Stripe account.

Comment: OMG yes it works. I can swear that I tried to remove this line yesterday and it did not work, but now it does. Awesome, thank you Paul.